# Custom bullet in editText inputType password

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I need to create custom bullet for password for editText and put some padding between bullet symbols.

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

For changing the character that is displayed you can call the method [setTransformationMethod (TransformationMethod method)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTransformationMethod(android.text.method.TransformationMethod)) and pass it a custom [PasswordTransformationMethod](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/text/method/PasswordTransformationMethod.html).

This could look something like the following:

```
public class AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }
    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; // Store char sequence
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
            return '*'; // This is the important part
        }
        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); // Return default
        }
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
        }
    }
};
```

and then set it like this:

```
textView.setTransformationMethod(new AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod());
```

For changing the padding and such you should use either use [textScaleX](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3AtextScaleX) or if you are at API Level 21+  use [letterSpacing](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:letterSpacing) in the XML.

Comment: thanks!
but what to do if I need to override characters with image?

Comment: Sorry, don't know a solution off the top of my head on that then.. You might want to check out the following two related questions though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891797/is-it-possible-to-replace-dots-in-password-edittext-with-custom-view and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797824/how-to-use-custom-image-for-edittext-password-like-axis-bank-app