# Change EditText dot to icon

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I am working on inputType of EditText. I want to change dot symbol to circle icon like this.

[image: circle]

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696868/custom-bullet-in-edittext-inputtype-password)

Comment: it shows * but I need to show circle and drawable return int