# How to replace the default password mask by a custom drawable, with delay on the last character?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I would like to replace the default password mask by a custom drawable, with a delay on the last character so that the user can see the last character before it is replaced by the drawable.

So far I managed to replace all the character by the drawable. However, I cannot add a delay. The last character is automatically replaced by the drawable. I have been trying with a coroutines but it does not change anything.

The TextWatcher on the EditText:

```
    paswword.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

        override fun afterTextChanged(source: Editable?) {

            val passwordDotDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.password_dot)
            passwordDotDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 49, 49)
            
            val spannableTag = Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            
            source?.forEachIndexed { index, char ->
                val image = ImageSpan(passwordDotDrawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_CENTER)
                if (index < source.lastIndex) {
                    source.setSpan(image, index, index + 1, spannableTag)
                } else if (index == source.lastIndex) {
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                        delay(1000L)
                        source.setSpan(image, source.lastIndex, source.length, spannableTag)
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    })
```

Any ideas would be very welcome.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Another approach: The dot it's displaying is just the character `'\u2022'`. Perhaps you could create a font which replaces this character and apply it? This way you don't have to deal with anything else.

Comment: There's also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29892375/2232127 which is meant for this type of task